# Xcopy and replacing a file

Tags: cmd, xcopy

When I'm using Xcopy command in *CMD* to copy and replace a file from the user's download location to another location, I'm getting invalid number of parameters.

Here's my code:

```
xcopy /y C:\%userprofile%\downloads\XXXXt\XXXX C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XXX\common\XXXX\XXXX\Managed\XXXX
```

The `XXX`'s represent game files for which we are replacing to *mod* the game.

Comment: Type `echo` %userprofile%`. Or `echo <your whole command line>`

Comment: I Tried Both. I'm not Getting The Error Anymore, but it's not successfully Replacing the File Now.

Comment: You have to read it to see your error.

Answer (score 0):

- `%USERPROFILE%` includes the drive letter. Replace `C:\%USERPROFILE%` with just `%USERPROFILE%`.
- There are space in `Program Files (x86)`, so you need to place the destination in double quotes.
- Overall, the command should then be `xcopy /y "%userprofile%\Downloads\XXXX\XXXX" "C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX\XXX\common\XXXX\XXXX\Managed\XXXX"`.